# How to find Percentage Change of Certain Values in Pandas at different varied Periods in a Single Column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, percentage

Let's say i have Column A, and Column B. Column A has numerical values, Column B has String Labels. depending on the values for Column A, the values for Column B is either "En", "Ex", "T", "0".  I want to find the Percentage Change between "En" and "Ex" in the column only.  For example Column A could have the value "10", and in Column B this would be labeled "En". Than later on multiple rows later, Column A could increase to Value "20", this would be labeled "Ex" in Column B. I want to find the Percentage Change between these 2 values, between "En" and "Ex" in Column B. The values of "En" and "Ex" could be at different rows in the column, they could be spread out anywhere in the column, not set at a consistent period between each other.  Also in the Column, the "Ex" Value will always come after the "En" Value in the column. Below is part of the screenshot of an example of the column,

[image]

Instead of looping through this column, is there a method or function for Pandas that can calculate this percentage change in this case ?

Comment: So here missing `Column A` ? Can you add expected ouput if create data sample in text form? [Please don't post images of data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi, i posted just the output of the Column b.  Column A are just numerical values. I looked at the link you pasted, that link is regarding code that is copied as an image. the image i posted is just the actual output, not code. By posting the actual output, i think it would show exactly what im talking about. the link that you pasted had a comment that reflected only to poste images if you feel like it explains the understanding better than other ways. I think it displays the issue im talking about . Also if the image takes away from search criteria for this question, i will delete the image.

Comment: I check again and seems here missing [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) also with expected ouput.

Comment: Column A has number values. For example Column A could have the value "10", and in Column B this would be labeled "En". Than later on multiple rows later, Column A could increase to Value "20", this would be labeled "Ex" in Column B.  I want to find the Percentage Change between these 2 values, between "En" and "Ex" in Column B.

Comment: OK, so missing `Column A` if want percentage change. Also is always perfect data it means first `En`, then another data, then `Ex` another data, then `En`, some data, `Ex`? Are always pairs? Or sometimes pairs are broken?

Comment: In another words other data are not important, only is necessary filter rows with `En, Ex` and count percentage change?

Comment: If your asking if "En" always comes before "Ex" ?, yes that is correct.  For "Ex" to emerge in the Column there must be an "En" before it somewhere in the Column.

Comment: Super, so there is same number of `En` and `Ex` values? So create pairs?

Comment: Yes exactly, for this example, only "En" and "Ex" are important.  Yes "En" and "Ex" are just used for filtering or labeling.

Comment: Yes, hypothetically they would always be the same number of pairs. But if dont have all the total data at the time, or if Ex condition did not occur yet, it would be different totals of En and Ex. But yes hypothetically it would be.

Comment: hmm, it is bad, because if not same, then solution failed.

Comment: potentially, It would not be the same at that the last row of data. But for everything else it would be the same.

Comment: OK, so please create sample data with both columns, with `It would not be the same at that the last row of data` and expected ouput.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? again, when i say the last row, its because the updated data has not been recieved it. but of course when the new data arrives, at some point the "Ex" would occur.

Comment: Super, so my solution working like need?

Comment: Or start understand why still again and again ask for input data with expected ouput? Because from description hard understand what need :(

Answer (score 0):

From text is not clear expected ouput:

```
df = df[df['Column B'].isin(['En','Ex'])].copy()
print (df)
   Column A Column B
0        10       En
1        20       Ex
2        50       En
3        10       Ex


df1 = df.assign(g = df.groupby('Column B').cumcount()).pivot('g','Column B','Column A')

df1['pct change'] = df1['Ex'].sub(df1['En']).div(df1['En']).mul(100)
print (df1)
Column B  En  Ex  pct change
g                           
0         10  20       100.0
1         50  10       -80.0
```